# Why do some bones in my armature disappear when I go into Edit mode?

Tags: armature, rigging, bones

I made a rig for a model of a dragon and for some reason,
when I go into *Edit Mode*, some of the **bones disappear**:

[image]

I don't know if this is relevant or not, but I created the rig using the standard release of 2.69, but now I'm using the standard version of 2.70.

[Here is my blend file.](http://pasteall.org/blend/28701)

Comment: @CoDEmanX Is this really a feature or is it a bug? It seems more like a bug that was mistaken for a feature to me. Do you know for sure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Unhide Bones

Your bones were hidden. To unhide them, once in Edit mode press <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> and your bones will be back!

[image]

### Hidden Bones are only Hidden in Specific Modes

It is worth noting that bones hidden in one mode may be visible in another mode, and vice-versa. Here is an explanation from the [Blender Manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmGe3.gif):

> Note that hidden bones are specific to a mode – i.e. you can hide some
>   bones in Edit mode, they will still be visible in Pose mode, and
>   vice-versa. Hidden bone in Pose mode are also invisible in Object
>   mode. And in Edit mode, the bone to hide must be fully selected, not
>   just his root or tip…

Comment: You saved me from submitting a bug report! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ALT + H  did not work for me.

I used **"/"** on the numpad instead and that worked.

Comment: Welcome to bse, Augi.  "/" on the numpad is local mode toggle, and has nothing to do with hiding / un-hiding bones.

Comment: Well, explain to me why ALT + H did not work and why "/" worked?

Doesn't matter what it's "intended" for, what matters is it helped me solve my problem and I shared it in hopes of helping someone else who runs into a similar issue.

Comment: I dont understand it either. Alt H should work. Same problem and / worked for me too. Alt H didnt.

Comment: It does matter what the tool is intended for. Alt+H and Numpad / do entirely different functions.

Comment: Alt + H did not work for me and "/" solved my problem.  

That is all I know.

Comment: If I had the reputation, I would post it as a separate answer.
My issue was layers. I had an IK bone on one layer, and the rest of my armature in the other.
I won't pretend to understand all of it, but this link helped me: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/layers.html
Activating the layer, selecting the object, then moving the object back to the original layer with "M" fixed it.